# Accessing Each Node in a list that is an index in a vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, std-pair

I am currently making a hash table by using a private data member `vector<list<pair<K, V>>> hashTable;`.

I need to access each list, and in turn, each pair for various different functions. I am currently doing so like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hashTable.capacity(); i++){
        list<pair<K,V>>* listPtr = hashTable[i];
for(pair<K,V>* pairPtr = listPtr->front(); pairPtr != listPtr->end(); pairPtr++){
                pair<K,V> tempPair;
                tempPair.first = pairPtr->first;
                tempPair.second = pairPtr->second;
                insert(tempPair);
            }
        }
}
```

The code above is part of my rehash function. Insert inserts the pair based on the hash functions which hashes based on the size of the vector. It's not really important. I just want to know how to get to each list and then each pair.

My question is, is there a better way to access each list and pair in the vector?

Comment: Well for a start it should be `hashTable.size()`. For a vector, capacity is not the same as size.

Comment: `list<pair<K,V>>* listPtr = hashTable[i];` does not compile. Maybe you meant `list<pair<K,V>>* listPtr = hashTable + i;`?

Comment: @john Sorry, I meant to type tempList as hashTable. That was a snippet from a different function. You're right, I should use size. I just tried compiling my code and see that. How do I access the list, and thus pairs, then?

Comment: Ditto `pair<K,V>* pairPtr = listPtr->front()` does not compile.

Comment: Why are you copying each pair into a temp and then inserting it... into something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to access each pair on each list is

```
for (const auto& list : hashTable)
{
    for (const auto& pair : list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

but the `insert` function in the code above worries me. If you are iterating over the vectors/lists while you are simultaneously modifying them, that changes things.

Comment: Holy crap I completely forgot about the ranged for loop. I haven't been able to use STL for any assignment really so I forgot about it. Could you elaborate on what this for loop is doing exactly? Also, why do you do it by reference?

Comment: The insert is a part of my rehash function. So it was a snippet of me assigning a tempTable to hashTable, clearing hashTable, resizing it, and then walking through tempTable to grab each pair and insert into hashTable using the hash function. IT hashes based off the hashTable's size

Comment: @Zevias The references avoid copying the entire list (or pair), instead the `list` and `pair` variable just refer to the lists and pairs in your hash table.

Comment: @Zevias And the loops just go through the enitre hash table from beginning to end.

Comment: @Zevias And as long as you are not modifying the data structure you are iterating over everything should be fine. Ranged for loops cannot be used if you are modifying the data structure you are iterating over.

Comment: Okay, the problem I am having now is, I don't want to iterate over the entire hashTable. For example, when I call `bool HashTable<K,V>::insert(const std::pair<K, V> & kv)`, it insert the pair parameter into the list of the index that `pair.first` hashes to. What can I use to say "let me access the front of the list at hashTable[x]" so that I can insert a pair into that list?

Comment: `auto pair = hashTable[x].front();` seems ok to me.

Comment: Does this return a pointer to a pair or a pointer to a list? I don't see how to go through each list at a given index. Do I increment `pair` from ` auto pair = hashTable[x].front();`?

Comment: I cannot compile auto pair = hashTable[x].front() for some reason.

Comment: `auto pair = hashTable[x].front()` compiles for me what error messge do you get?

Comment: `front` will return (a reference to) a pair, not a pointer, but there's no way to get from that pair to the next pair in the list.

Comment: If you want an iterator to the front of a list for insertion purposes that would be `hashTable[x].begin()`. And that iterator can be incremented to get to the next item in the list. But aren't you now talking about modifying the hash table as you iterator over it? That really does bring additional problems (but is still possible of course).